# Using robot_pose_ekf output for Navigation stack

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on a robot similar to a turtlebot that uses the gyro from the turtlebot and encoders for tracking movement.  I setup the robot_pose_ekf to take in the data and it is working correctly.  I am now confused at what to do with the output of robot_pose_ekf.  It is in the format [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) and the navigation stack requires [nav_msgs/Odometry.](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)  I am unsure if I am heading in the right direction with this but the overall goal is to combine the gyro and the encoder readings and then send it to the nav stack.  Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11101/using-robot_pose_ekf-output-for-navigation-stack/) by [jbeck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/862/jbeck27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-09-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_pose_ekf broadcasts the tf transform from odom_combined to base_link (odom_combined -> base_link) which amcl uses to compute the position of the robot. A good explanation of how this works can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C92bxCr05Gs

The turtlebot_navigation package does what you are describing. Checkout the autonomously navigating in a known map tutorial. (http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map)

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbeck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/862/jbeck27/) on 2011-10-14**:
I want the combined gyro and wheel odometry to be given to the local planner.   robot_pose_ekf publishes "odom_combined" that is not a nav_msgs/Odometry message.  What is given to the local planner for the turtlebot?

**Comment by [jbeck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/862/jbeck27/) on 2011-10-14**:
That didn't solve the problem.   I think I can clarify what I need now though.  the robot_pose_ekf publishes a tf frame that amcl uses.  What I need is some way to give the local planner the "odom" message.  I am referencing the diagram in http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base .

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-02**:
in the configuration files you should see a line:   you need to set the param to the frame you want to use. It's in the amcl_turtlebot.launch file.

**Comment by [jbeck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/862/jbeck27/) on 2011-09-02**:
Thank you for the response.  I actually had already found your videos, nice job btw.  I guess a better phrasing of the question would if you run robot_pose_ekf and the nav stack is using it in the AMCL, what do you send as "odom" to the local_planner inside the navigation system?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[robot_pose_ekf](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) subscribes only to the Pose portion of odom to give the estimated pose.

whereas [move_base](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base) takes only the velocity information from odom. if you look at the diagram, the "odom" message goes to the local planner which is the [base_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner). This subscribes to odom which uses the velocity for trajectory calculations

so I don't think you can use the robot_pose_ekf output for navigation planning

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2